# Gtk Button not triggering button release event on left click

Tags: button, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm

I'm wondering why a GtkButton's button-release-event is not triggered by left mouse button clicks. In the following code (using gtkmm3) the button fires the *clicked* event on a left button click and the *button-release* event when clicked on using any other mouse button. I'd like to determine whether any modifier keys are being pressed while clicking the button, so I need the additional information provided by the button release event. Is there a way to get it to trigger on left clicks as well?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

void clicked()
{
    std::cout << "clicked" << std::endl;
}

bool button_released( GdkEventButton* evt )
{
    std::cout << "button released" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app =
        Gtk::Application::create( argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base" );

    Gtk::Window window;
    window.set_default_size( 300, 200 );

    Gtk::Button* btn = Gtk::manage( new Gtk::Button( "Click me!" ) );
    btn->add_events( Gdk::BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK );
    btn->signal_clicked().connect( sigc::ptr_fun( clicked ) );
    btn->signal_button_release_event().connect( sigc::ptr_fun( button_released ) );
    window.add( *btn );

    window.show_all();

    return app->run( window );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button implementation handles the button release event itself (if it is the primary mouse button, usually the left one) and propagates a `GtkButton` specific `clicked`/`button-release-event` signal instead.

[Source](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkbutton.c#n1932)

**Update:**

If you really got special needs you either can write a widget handling button presses yourself (either by starting from scratch or starting from a copy of `GtkButton`) or you subclass and overwrite the handler for that specific event (not sure this is possible, there seem to be quite a few functions doing some magic with events in `GtkButton` - if it is possible, then just wrap that callbacked hooked to the signal specific function pointer and make it call the original callback (but do not care about the return value) and always return `GDK_PROPAGATE_EVENT`)

Comment: Too bad the second half of the answer is missing, but I'll still accept it, as the source definitely answers the question. I have to say, I don't see the point in supressing the general button release event, even if there is a button specific event, so I'll have to look if it's possible to override that function.

Comment: Yes it is, but you need to subclass `GtkButton` (the C one, not sure if this works if you do it with C++) and overwrite the function pointer for the `GtkWidget` event an make sure to return `FALSE` (or since a few versions `GDK_EVENT_PROPAGATE`). Don't know why half the answer got eaten... gonna fix it soonish - currently no clue what I wanted/did add there.

Answer (score 0):

X signal events (generally, the ones that have a boolean return to indicate that the event has been fully handled) are a little different than other signals, particularly in gtkmm:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-xeventsignals.html.en

So try passing false as an extra parameter to connect().

However, I don't think it would be a good idea to change the behaviour of a standard widget. People don't expect to use keyboard modifiers when pressing on buttons. A checkbox, or an extra button, would be clearer for the user.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information. I seem to have skipped that part of the docs. I'll try passing the extra parameter, when I find the time to continue that project. I do agree that using keyboard modifiers with buttons is a bad idea, but it's just a prototype application and I wanted to avoid widget clutter for rarely used functionality. As you said, an additional button would be better suited.